# Retreiving the element position using xpath for each and every element with in the same parent

Tags: xml, xpath

I have multiple table elements with in a same chapter. Also i have multiple chapters . I want to name each table like (Table : chapter# . Table#). The xml file looks like this

```
<bookmap>
   <chapter>
      <table>This is first table of first chapter</table>
      <table>This is second table of first chapter</table>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
      <table>This is first table of second chapter</table>
      <table>This is second table of second chapter</table>
   </chapter>
</bookmap>
```

Here i need XPATH expression to fetch the table number . Am getting the chapter number like "count(preceding:chapter)+1". In the same way am trying to get the XPATH expression for Table number.How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `preceding-sibling`:

```
count($table/preceding-sibling::table)+1
```

Assuming your `table` element is stored in `$table`

Comment: am not using XSLT to define a variable.Am using Arbortext styler. So i need an expression that directly results in the table #.

Comment: I don't get the problem!? If `count(preceding:chapter)+1"` works for you then `count(preceding-sibling:chapter)+1"` should work for you as well.